# backbone boilerplate: How to start the development server

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I've cloned Backbone boilerplate which comes with an example Todo app. I have also read that the boilerplate comes with a development server, but I don't know how to start it. In the tutorial, it says you can run this command

```
node build/server
```

but I get an error saying that it can't find the module  /build/server

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2):

If you've installed [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) it should be as simple as changing directory to the root of the TODO application and running the following command (although you may also need to add the path to `node` to your environment settings):

```
bbb server
```

You should then be able to access the example on localhost:8000.

Comment: Just as an FYI, you can change the server values in grunt.js to run bbb on a specific host and port.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI, you can change the server values in grunt.js to run bbb on a specific host and port.

```
server: {
   host: "10.111.X.1", port: 3303,
   ...
}
```